# Static date format when submit on Servicenow form

Tags: javascript, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

We do have a multiple forms on servicenow that has a date field. All date field could only accept this default format **YYYY-mm-dd**. And when the user will going to change the default date format on their servicenow profile/settings and then fill-up and submit the form that has a date field, the result is that the date value going to be invalid due to invalid date format. How can I make the format static regardless of the users date format settings on servicenow? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = g_form.getValue('your_date_field');
if(getDateFromFormat(val, g_user_date_time_format) === 0){
   //invalid date 
   g_form.addErrorMessage("Date is invalid")
}else{
   //success, you have valid date
}
```

**Make use of current user profile properties:**

```
g_user_date_time_format //gives date time format 
g_user_date_format // date format
g_user_decimal_separator // for number decimal separator
g_user_grouping_separator // for number grouping
```

If you are doing at **server-end** use: `gs.getDateTimeFormat()`

```
GlideSession gs = GlideSession.getCurrent();
gs.getDateTimeFormat();
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil B N. We have so many forms on different pages that has date field. Is it possible to make it global date format of YYYY-mm-dd regardless of the user settings date format?

Comment: That would be against user's preferences. But nevertheless, you can always save in single format. What is the business use case to restrict user to one format?

Comment: yeah we need to make it to one format its because everytime the user change the date format on their profile settings, then any format form that has a date field when they submit it triggers an error and that will serve them as blockers and they cant proceed.